# I'm doing multiple radial gradients in CSS and I need to add a horizontal and vertical gradient as well, but it's changing to one solid color

Tags: html, css

This is what I currently have. The image and radial-gradients so far are working, but I'm not sure how to add the horizontal and vertical radial-gradients. What I still need to add are radial-gradients with a size of 5% in the vertical and horizontal positions placed at 90% and 10%.  with the color being white stopping at 15% followed by the color rgba(0,0,0,0) stopping at 40%. I'm just unsure how to get the vertical and horizontal positioning. The problem doesn't specify a shape for the radial-gradient either. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epG4I.jpg)

```css
body {
  background: radial-gradient(circle closest-corner at 40% 70%, white 15%, rgba(151, 151, 151, 0.5) 50%), radial-gradient(circle closest-corner at 80% 40%, white 15%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 30%), url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/epG4I.jpg);
  background-color: rgb(151, 151, 151);
}
```

Comment: I have edited your post and set a snippet, you can edit it yourself again to add any more details you think necessary. **About mutiple backrounds, the first one is on top of the next one**, and so on as many you set. Your code will show the image and then the gradients behind it.To have the image behind the gradient, put the gradient first. You may also use `background-blend-mode` for other mixing effects.

Comment: Thanks for your post. I'm very new to this stuff currently taking an intro to html class. about the image stacking, the image is appearing right and the first two circle gradients are showing ontop of the image like they're supposed to. This is the current step I'm on that will be included with the body element I've already put together.
A radial gradient with a size of 5% in the horizontal and vertical directions placed at (90%, 10%) with the color white stopping at 15% and followed by the color rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) stopping at 40%

Comment: Okay, can you link your css to a fake image of the size of yours ? You can use https://placeimg.com/ or  https://dummyimage.com/ or any other generator you find, so we have a better view of what you currently have ;)  like : `background: url(https://placeimg.com/200/100/nature), radial-gradient(....` From a fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/1jfv7ac4/ your code with an image hides the gradients behing the image

Comment: Probably a dumb question, but how would I link the css to the fake image?

Comment: just edit your post and snippet, then save your edit ;) Welcome on SO BTW

Comment: I think I did it right, but i'm not sure

Comment: it needs to be the full url  (https://..... )  ;)

Comment: Fixed it I believe

Comment: yep, for me it doesn't show anymore the gradients, do you see them (which browser do you use if so )

Comment: I use chrome, but I also changed the code in my project to putting the img in end of the list, so let me do that to the snipet was well.

Comment: perfect, In your project did you add contents in body or did you give a min-height to body ? like `body{min-height:100vh;}` or any other value that suits your needs ?

Comment: No, currently building this project in "Cengage Mindtap",. It tells me every step I need to do then validates to see if the code applies the correct styles. however the margins and everything for the body were written already. If you want I can post the code for the body from the css sheet that's already been completed for this project.

Comment: So if body is empty, it needs a min-height so the gradient will show correctly . add `body{min-height:100vh;}` and it should be fine

Comment: Thanks. I got the checks to pass, but as far as I know I skipped a step, but it said there was 0% difference. O well time to move on lmao.